# How do I create a repeating charge using redstone/repeaters?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Despite having some experience with Minecraft, the use of redstone is one thing that I never managed to get the hang of.

I have no issue creating simple works such as redstone doors and other manually powered mechanisms, but one trick has managed to elude me. This technique is a repeating redstone charge.

How would I create a repeating charge in a redstone circuit? Despite my tampering and experimentation with redstone repeaters and such, I've been unable to prepare my own answer.

Comment: As in, a signal that pulses on and off?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'm having difficulties creating a mechanism with a redstone charge that pulses on and off.

Comment: Wow... a so primitive question that wasn't even on Arquade till today :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to make a redstone clock; a signal that pulses on and off.

There are many different ways to do this. For example,

- Make a circuit like this.
  [image: 1]
- Power it.
  [image: 2]
- Mine the redstone torch. (The circuit should still be powered.)
- Mine one of the redstone on one of the corners then place it almost immediately.
  [image: 3]
  [image: 4]
  There you go!

Additionally, a more complex and less compact way of doing it is:

- Make a design like this:
  [image: 5]
- Add a block on the **sticky piston**, and power it with the empty spot on the left.
  [image: 6]

I hope this helped! If not please comment what is wrong! Oh yeah, welcome to the Arqade!

Comment: (Appreciation for the warm welcome) Yes, this did help. Thank you very much. While the topic is open, would the method of construction vary much or at all concerning larger builds?

Comment: Glad to help! I hope you have a good time here.

Comment: So, the method of construction depends on the first and second design. For the first design, it does matter, but you can make it longer, change, and add repeaters. For the second; less efficient design, you can change the block on the piston. The methods of making them do not change very much when we are speaking larger builds. I'm sure there are some more compact and different ways of making a redstone clocks but I do not know any others.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've figured it out, and I highly doubt that I will forget it from here.

Comment: Awesome! Happy Minecrafting!

Answer (score 2):

This is the most compact (so far) way of doing it:

First, get at least 4 redstone dust and one redstone comparator and a lever or redstone torch. Next, lay down three dust in an L shape. The final redstone dust will extend anywhere except the side with the lever.
In the 4th corner of the L shape, put a comparator facing any way. After that, toggle the comparator so the redstone torch is on. Finally, place a lever behind it and power on.

It will look like this:

[image: Result]

Comment: Most compact setup is 2 hoppers aiming to each other, one item inside one of them and at least one comparator. Bingo, 3 blocks used....

Comment: 4* since a comparator must sit on a block.

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites True.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjLx3.jpg) is a collection of minecraft clocks, from [this](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/351967-ultimate-collection-of-redstone-circuits) circuit list.  I'll upload a few here so this isn't link only:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Compact, silent, stable.

Comment: Can you remove Clock #8? I already went over it in one of my answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Self-Resetting Clock (and its variants)

A self-resetting clock is one that does this:

- Piston is off.
- Wire goes through the block.
- Piston is powered by powered wire.
- Piston is on.
- Piston moves the block.
- Wires does not go through the piston arm.
- Piston is not powered by not powered wire.
- The cycle starts over.

Here are some visual examples of these:

[image]

#### Most Compact

Start off by placing a lever that powers a repeater.

[image]

After that, place a block where the repeater faces.

[image]

Place a sticky piston facing the block on either side of it, except for the.

[image]

Connect some redstone wire from the side that is **NOT** opposite of the sticky piston to the back of the sticky piston.

[image]

Test it out!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful answer. It would really help if the images were more brightly lit. A Minecraft day is only 20 minutes, so you would only have to wait ~5-10 minutes tops till morning from the time night falls in Minecraft. Or, assuming that because you have the resources to get Redstone in Minecraft, you likely also have access to a bed (such as if you are in creative mode and do not know commands). Cheers!